# SKScene.backgroundColor not working. Always default color

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Hi I'm setting my SKScene's backgroundColor property in its didMoveToView function like this :

```
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

But the background colour is always the default grey. I have another simple SpriteKit test project and setting the background colour the same way works.

I've removed all nodes from my scene to rule out the possibility that the background is being overlayed.

Do you know what might be stopping my background colour appearing?

Thanks.

Comment: did you check whether this line is executed at all?

Comment: It's a valid question, specifically if it's an oddly odd issue. I prefer to start with the basics before suggesting to depolarize the inverse keystroke confabulator. Another question: do you start with this scene or was there an active scene before or does one follow this scene immediately? Perhaps one scene didn't deallocate or this scene is replaced with another instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it works as expected for me.

Here's my initial scene, HelloScene.m

```
#import "HelloScene.h"
#import "NewScene.h"

@interface HelloScene ()
@property BOOL contentCreated;
@end

@implementation HelloScene

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    if (!self.contentCreated) {
        [self createSceneContents];
        self.contentCreated = YES;
    }
}

- (void)createSceneContents
{
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.333 green:0.780 blue:0.961 alpha:1];
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
    [self addChild:[self newHelloNode]];
}

- (SKLabelNode *)newHelloNode
{
    SKLabelNode *helloNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    helloNode.name = @"helloNode";
    helloNode.text = @"Hello !";
    helloNode.fontSize = 42;
    helloNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    return helloNode;
}

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#pragma mark - Event Handling - iOS
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self runHelloNodeAction];
}

#else

#pragma mark - Event Handling - OS X
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [self runHelloNodeAction];
}

#endif

- (void)runHelloNodeAction
{
    SKNode *helloNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"helloNode"];
    if (helloNode != nil) {
        helloNode.name = nil;

        SKAction *moveUpAndZoom = [SKAction group:@[[SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:100.0 duration:0.5],
                                                    [SKAction scaleTo:1.5 duration:0.5]]];
        SKAction *fadeAway = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.25];
        SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        SKAction *moveSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUpAndZoom, fadeAway, remove]];

        [helloNode runAction:moveSequence completion:^{
            SKScene *newScene = [[NewScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
            SKTransition *doors = [SKTransition doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:0.5];
            [self.view presentScene:newScene transition:doors];
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

Here's my second scene, NewScene.m

```
#import "NewScene.h"

@interface NewScene ()
@property BOOL contentCreated;
@end

@implementation NewScene

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    if (!self.contentCreated) {
        [self createSceneContents];
        self.contentCreated = YES;
    }
}

- (void)createSceneContents
{
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor purpleColor];
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
}

@end
```